# Error en calcular Diferencia en meses de dos Fechas en php

Tags: php, date

Hola estoy queriendo sacar la diferencia en meses de dos fechas, saco los datos de una tabla:
el codigo es:

```
    <?php
        $fechafinal = Date('yy-m-d');
        echo "Fecha Final: ". $fechafinal."<br>";
        $actual=0; //Tiene un Ultimo Trabajo
        if ($row['Hasta1'] != '0000-00-00'){
            $fechainicial = $row['Hasta1'];
        }else{
            if ($row['Desde1'] != '0000-00-00'){
                $fechainicial = $row['Desde1'];
                $actual=1;//TrabajoActual
            }
            $actual=2;//Nunca Trabajo
        }
        echo "Fecha Desde: ". $row['Desde1']."<br>";    
        echo "Fecha Hasta: ". $row['Hasta1']."<br>";
        echo "Fecha Inicial: ". $fechainicial."<br>";
        $diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);
$meses = ( $diferencia->y * 12 ) + $diferencia->m;
echo "Diferencia en Meses: ". $fechafinal;
```

al correrlo, el codigo me da este error.

```
Fecha Final: 2020-05-20
Fecha Desde: 1998-05-26
Fecha Hasta: 2017-10-16
Fecha Inicial: 2017-10-16

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function diff() on string in /home/justrisc/public_html/phpAux/ListadoCandidatos.php:80 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/justrisc/public_html/phpAux/ListadoCandidatos.php on line 80
```

La linea 80 es la que tiene este codigo

```
$diferencia = $fechainicial->diff($fechafinal);
```

No se que hago mal, hay alguna otra forma mas facil de hacerlo?

Comment: En la asignación inicial estas poniendo $fechafinal = Date('yy-m-y'); es decir estas poniendo el año (20) luego nuevamente el año (20), el mes y finalmente nuevamente el año, ¿eso es correcto?, si quieres la fecha en formato AAA-MM-DD, debes ponerla Y-m-d

Comment: Si, es verdad, muchas gracias,  no obstante lo corregí (y edite en la pregunta), igual me da el mismo error.

Comment: veo que traes el valor de desde1 y hasta1 de la DB, que DB estás usando y en qué formato viene la fecha?

Comment: Son dos campos date, lo toma bien ya que como veras lo publica en pantalla.

Comment: tambien probe poniendo:
$fechainicial = date($row['Desde1']);
En ambos campos, y me da mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estuve revisando y preferí usar la funcion date_diff() (es básicamente diff()), aqui hay mas información por si quieres cambiar algo: [date_diff()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date-diff.php). Al final creo haber llegado al resultado que necesita, espero te sirva. Suerte.

```
<?php
$desde = date_create('1998-05-26');
$hasta = date_create('2017-10-16');


$fechafinal = Date('Y-m-d');
echo "Fecha Final: ". $fechafinal."<br>";
$actual=0; //Tiene un Ultimo Trabajo
if ($hasta != '0000-00-00'){
    $fechainicial = $hasta;
}else{
    if ($desde != '0000-00-00'){
        $fechainicial = $desde;
        $actual=1;//TrabajoActual
    }
    $actual=2;//Nunca Trabajo
}
echo "Fecha Desde: ". $desde->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";    
echo "Fecha Hasta: ". $hasta->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
echo "Fecha Inicial: ". $fechainicial->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
$diferencia = date_diff($desde, $hasta);
$diferencia = $diferencia->format('%y')*12 + $diferencia->format('%m'); 
echo "Diferencia en Meses: ".$diferencia ;
?>
```

Aqui otra forma por si quisieras la diferencia en años, meses y dias.

```
<?php
$desde = date_create('1998-05-26');
$hasta = date_create('2017-10-16');


$fechafinal = Date('Y-m-d');
echo "Fecha Final: ". $fechafinal."<br>";
$actual=0; //Tiene un Ultimo Trabajo
if ($hasta != '0000-00-00'){
    $fechainicial = $hasta;
}else{
    if ($desde != '0000-00-00'){
        $fechainicial = $desde;
        $actual=1;//TrabajoActual
    }
    $actual=2;//Nunca Trabajo
}
echo "Fecha Desde: ". $desde->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";    
echo "Fecha Hasta: ". $hasta->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
echo "Fecha Inicial: ". $fechainicial->format('Y-m-d')."<br>";
$diferencia = date_diff($desde, $hasta);    
echo "Diferencia: ". $diferencia->format('%y años, %m meses, %d dias');
?>
```

Comment: Hola Josue, entonces decis que haga esto?
$desde = date_create($row['Desde1']);
$hasta = date_create($row['Hasta2']);

Comment: dependería del tipo de valor que trajera la consulta a la DB si ya es de tipo fecha no sería necesario, intenta sin eso y me dices cómo te va

Comment: Funciono haciendo 
$desde = date_create($row['Desde1']); $hasta = date_create($row['Hasta2']);
Muchas Gracias  @Josue Arriola